# setTimeout time interval ignored in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timeout

I've googled and come across a number of similar issues where people are trying to setTimeout in a jQuery plugin but to be i'm struggling with the answers, this is not a lazy post.

I am trying to achieve a delay in calling animate to hide some content, so for example if the user hovers over some area, some more content swings into view and hides the original. Then when the user moves the mouse away after 2 seconds the original content is returned.

The animation works as expected albeit ignoring the timeout. This is what I cannot get my head around!

Any assistance with the code would as always be greatly appreciated!

Here's the simplified code, focusing on the animation but I have left in place the plugin structure: -

```
;(function($){
$.fn.extend({         
    pluginName: function(options) {
        // - Settings list and the default values           
        var defaults = {
            width: this.css('width'),
        };

        var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);   

        return this.each(function() {

        // --  Globals
            var o = options;    
            var timeoutID;

        function deceptionAnimate(display) {
            if(display == 1) {
                obj.clearQueue().animate({
                                        'top': 0,
                                        'left': -o.width 
                                        }, o.interval, o.easing);               
            } else if(display == 0) {
                obj.clearQueue().animate({
                                        'top': 0,
                                        'left': 0
                                        }, o.interval, o.easing)                
            } 
        }

        function delaydeceptionAnimate () {
            timeoutID = window.setTimeout(deceptionAnimate(0), 2000);
        }

        // ---- Initiate
        function init() {   
                        // ----- Animate

                        $(document).on(o.eventTrigger, wrapperID, function() {
                            deceptionAnimate(1);
                        });
                        $(document).on('mouseout', wrapperID, function() {
                            delaydeceptionAnimate(0);
                        });     
        }       
        // Call
        init();

        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.setTimeout(deceptionAnimate(0), 2000);
```

You are *calling* `deceptionAnimate` with parameter `0` and then passing its return value (`null`) to `setTimeout` as the function to be called.

In this particular case, you can rewrite `deceptionAnimte` like so:

```
function deceptionAnimate(display) {
    if( display) { /* code to show box */ }
    else { /* code to hide box */ }
}
```

Then use this:

```
window.setTimeout(deceptionAnimate, 2000);
```

But in the more general case, to pass an argument to the function to be delayed, use an anonymous function:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {deceptionAnimate(0);}, 2000);
```

Comment: Just so if it isn't clear, `deceptionAnimate(0)` is a function *call*; `deceptionAnimate` is a function *reference*. You want to give `setTimeout` a function to call when the timer ticks out, so you should be giving it a function reference.

Comment: Great thanks, and thanks for the explanation of the reference both really helped me understand the problem here. I decided to go for this as the answer because what I was looking for was a solution that would allow me to modify the deceptionAnimate func to work with the delay.

Comment: @kolink, i have same issue please look at that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178170/settimeout-not-working-with-custom-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You want to be careful about how you write the timeout function call. Here, you're actually calling delayedDeceptionAnimate rather than passing it as a function attribute to the setTimeout function.

Try rewriting that block as this:

```
function delaydeceptionAnimate () {
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(function() {
        deceptionAnimate(0);
        }, 2000);
}
```

This way, you're passing a callback function that then calls the delayedDeceptionAnimate function!